# What is the criteria for getting gold stars in Rock Band 2?

Tags: rock-band-2

What do you have to do (in terms of score I guess) to get the gold stars? I've seen a few youtube videos with them, but even when I score 100% or close on a song I never get them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two points have to be met in order for you to obtain gold stars:

- You must be playing on Expert difficulty (all instruments if there are multiple players; if guitar, bass and vocals are on Expert, but drums are on Hard, you won't get gold stars no matter how well you perform).
- You must achieve a certain number of points (generally around 1.4x the 5-star score in RB2); this can require taking an optimal overdrive path through the song, but doesn't necessarily require getting 100%. For drums, you can find a list of optimal activations [here](http://rockband.yajags.com/drumstats/), and tips on improving your score [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241/how-do-i-achieve-the-top-score-playing-drums-solo-in-rock-band-2). For guitar/bass, you can find a list of paths and the scores different score-improving techniques will optimally net you [here](http://www.apathtoofar.com/paths/rb2/expert/guitar/). For vocals, here are the paths for [RB1](http://rockband.scorehero.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8091), [RB2](http://rockband.scorehero.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14707), and [DLC](http://rockband.scorehero.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17397). [This site](http://rockband.yajags.com/cutoffs/) shows you the cutoffs for each star ranking on the instruments and difficulties of your choosing for all games/DLC; put the instruments on expert to see the gold star cutoff.

Comment: The general applicable rule is that the Gold Star scores for RB2 are around 1.4x the 5 star score.